# Android: realtime Firebase Rules

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I would like to know how to secure my rules. I tried to use `auth.uid != null` in read and write.

But if a new user is trying to login or create new account it won't succeed and gives me permission denied.

I want to secure Users and restrict read for user himself and his data only:

I tried to use `auth.uid != null` but already reg user won't be able to login, and new users can't create account. So I had to make it true for public write and read. Any solution?

cuz even auth.uid != null , authenticated user can read the entire data of all users not only himself

This is my rules copy:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "root.child('Admins').child(auth.uid).exists()",
    "Admins": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "Users": {
      ".read": true,
        ".write": true 
    },
    "PrivateWork": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": false
    },
    "Likes": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    },
    "Work": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": false
    },
    "videos": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

RegisterActivity:

```
//Check if num already exist
binding.continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (binding.phoneNumBox.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            binding.phoneNumBox.setError(getString(R.string.please_enter_phone));
        } else if (binding.phoneNumBox.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
            binding.phoneNumBox.setError(getString(R.string.enter_valid_phone));
        } else {
        DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        userRef.orderByChild("phoneNumber")
                .equalTo(binding.phoneNumBox.getText().toString())
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegPhoneNumActivity.this, getString(R.string.already_exist), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegPhoneNumActivity.this, OTPActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", binding.phoneNumBox.getText().toString());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
```

LoginActivity:

```
//Check if num already exist
binding.loginContinueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (binding.loginPhoneNumBox.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            binding.loginPhoneNumBox.setError(getString(R.string.please_enter_phone_numb));
        } else if (binding.loginPhoneNumBox.getText().toString().length() <= 6) {
            binding.loginPhoneNumBox.setError(getString(R.string.plaese_enter_valid_phone_num));
        } else {
            userRef.orderByChild("phoneNumber")
                    .equalTo(binding.loginPhoneNumBox.getText().toString())
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneLoginActivity.this, LoginVerifyPhoneActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", binding.loginPhoneNumBox.getText().toString());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.phone_num_doesnt_exist), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own; they only become active one you run code against them. Please edit your question to include [minimal code too](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and be sure to show in that code how it meets the conditions in your rules (e.g. by logging the UID).

Comment: updated with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow a user to only read their own data, you'll need to:

1. Use the user's UID as the **key** for their node.
2. Secure access as shown in the documentation on [content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

For the rules that means your `Users` node becomes this:

```
"Users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
},
```

And the code to access it then becomes:

```
userRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUID())
       .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

---

While it **is** also possible to check the phone number of the signed in user against the value of the node in the database, there too the user will have to be signed in already. If that is the case for you,  check the documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules).

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Comment: this happens when new user tring to create account or even trying to login, since new user hasn't yet got uid for first time

Comment: Your `"auth.uid != null"` rules indicate that you only want a logged in user to be able to write to the database, so it makes no sense to try and write to the database before the user is signed in.

Comment: true, then what rules would look like if i want that new users can create account and already reg and want to login to be able to read only his data, or it's not possible and i need to keep it .read, .write true for full read and write, but anyone would be able to download entire users data

Comment: The rules in my answer allow the user to read their own data, if you stored that data under their UID. The first link in my answers explains more about that scenario.

Comment: okay , then already reg user trying to login new how would he be able to allow read data so that he can login, cuz auth.uid won't give uid before login so how to login?

Comment: and thanks for giving me your time

Comment: if i use read: auth.uid !=null or == $uid still gives me permission denied

Comment: I very much have a feeling we're talking about a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.  Are you trying to allow only users that are in your database to sign in?

Comment: my app uses phone auth to login and signup, now when new user try to create account if firebase rules is auth.uid != null he won't be able to create account, and if he is already reg and want login with phone he wouldn't be able to access and get permission denied so what is the rules to allow login, create account and same time secure database so no one would just download entire user database

Comment: When say "create account", I assume you mean writing details to the database, right? In the order you say things now, they first login, and then write to the database. That is the normal way to handle additional registration details with Firebase, and means the user has a UID by the time they try to write to the database - so the rules I shared will work.